# Lines around .png images in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, png, vertical-alignment

I have a strange problem...  At my place of employment, I am in charge of updating and maintaining the Spiceworks user portal, on which we place company news along with a bunch of other stuff.  PROBLEM IS...  I have created a .png image to round corners of a picture which I have set as a background for the table.  I have it made such that it looks perfect on both Firefox and Chrome, but on Internet Explorer, the .png files for some reason have an outline around the outside of them.  Attached is a comparison:

A picture can be found at:  http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/CFvsIE_zps1edbce9c.png

I have tried everything I can think of...  The vertical-align css class is applied to the image, so I attempted to apply another class with the same styles to the td tag... no dice.  I even attempted to apply the valign="bottom" property to the td tag.  Nothing.  As you can see, it looks fine on Chrome/Firefox but unfortunately, the majority of the staff here use IE.  For purposes of being professional and having the page look the same regardless of browser type, I really want to get this ironed out.  Has anyone ever dealt with this before?  Here's my HTML that I'm using:

```
<p><style type="text/css">
    img.rotate90deg
    {
        display: inline-block;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
            -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
            -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
        vertical-align: top;
    }
img.rotate180deg
    {
        display: inline-block;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
            -o-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Opera */
            -moz-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Firefox */
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
img.rotate270deg
    {
        display: inline-block;
            transform: rotate(270deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
            -o-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Opera */
            -moz-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
table.nextevent
    {
        display: block;
        border: none;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style></p>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr width="100%">
        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="95%">
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr width="100%">
                    <td width="40%">
                    <h2 align="left">Lunch - Jose Pepper's</h2>
                    <table align="left">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr colspan="2">
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <h3 style="text-align: left; ">&nbsp; When:</h3>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <h3>Tuesday, February 19, 2013</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="20%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="40%" align="center">
                    <table class="nextevent" height="201" width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background: url(http://blogs.kansas.com/dining/files/2010/07/chiliconqueso-thumb-1-300x201.jpg)">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="20" width="20"><img align="left" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/Untitled_zpsbe7f3ae8.png" width="20" height="20" alt="" /></td>
                                <td height="20" width="260">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td height="20" width="20"><img class="rotate90deg" align="left" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/Untitled_zpsbe7f3ae8.png" width="20" height="20" alt="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="161" width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td height="161" width="260">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td height="161" width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="20" width="20"><img class="rotate270deg" align="left" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/Untitled_zpsbe7f3ae8.png" width="20" height="20" alt="" /></td>
                                <td height="20" width="260">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td height="20" width="20"><img class="rotate180deg" align="left" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/Untitled_zpsbe7f3ae8.png" width="20" height="20" alt="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head im sure earlier versions of IE don't support transparent png's very well.

You could achieve the rounding with css. Rounded corners are supported quite widely now and you can get it to work on ie 6 & 7 with css3pie http://css3pie.com/

Try adding this to an image in css.

```
.img{
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    border-radius: 18px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 18px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
```

It should round the corners of normal images, so you don't need to do it manually. This will work for Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome & newer versions of IE. To get it to work with IE6 & IE7 you should grab the files from from css3pie ( http://css3pie.com/ ). I would usually make separate IE specific CSS files for the versions in question.

In these css files define the image and include the path to the PIE.htc file. Something like

```
.img{
behavior: url(path/to/pie_files/PIE.htc);
}
```

Its pretty straight forward once you get the hang of it, good luck!